How can I optimize SQL code when needing to repeatedly call a scalar function for a substantial number of rows?
Here is a table called 'Operations' with a bunch of dates, and I need to find the time differences between six specific dates. But when I try to do this, it takes forever because the table has a lot of records and I have to call a scalar function for each record six times. We must only count the time during working hours (excluding holidays and Sundays), that's why a scalar function is needed. It's very very slow. How can I do this faster?
I created this scalar function:
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetWorkingHoursDifferenceForTheSameWorkingHours]
(
@StartDate DATETIME, 
@EndDate DATETIME, 
@BusinessDayStartHour VARCHAR(20), 
@BusinessDayEndHour VARCHAR(20),   
@BusinessDayStartHourForSaturday VARCHAR(20), 
@BusinessDayEndHourForSaturday VARCHAR(20)   
)
 
RETURNS DECIMAL(10, 3)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MinutesDifference DECIMAL(10, 3)
    DECLARE @Holidays Table (HDate DateTime, Recurring BIT)  
 
    INSERT INTO @Holidays (HDate, Recurring) 
    SELECT h.HDay, h.Recurring FROM HrNav.Core.OffDays AS h WITH (NOLOCK)  
 
    
    SET @MinutesDifference = 0.0

 
    IF DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday')
    BEGIN
        IF CONVERT(TIME, @StartDate) > @BusinessDayEndHour
        BEGIN
            SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(CONVERT(DATE, @StartDate) AS DATETIME)) + @BusinessDayStartHour
        END
    END
    ELSE IF DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) = 'Saturday'
    BEGIN
        IF CONVERT(TIME, @StartDate) > @BusinessDayEndHourForSaturday
        BEGIN
            SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, 2, CAST(CONVERT(DATE, @StartDate) AS DATETIME)) + @BusinessDayStartHourForSaturday
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, CAST(CONVERT(DATE, @StartDate) AS DATETIME)) + @BusinessDayStartHour
    END
 
 
 
 
 
 
    IF DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @EndDate) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday')
    BEGIN
        IF CONVERT(TIME, @EndDate) > @BusinessDayEndHour
        BEGIN
            SET @EndDate = CAST(CONVERT(DATE, @EndDate) AS DATETIME) + @BusinessDayEndHour
        END
    END
 
 
 
 
    WHILE @StartDate < @EndDate
    BEGIN
        IF DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday')
        BEGIN
            IF CONVERT(TIME, @StartDate) >= @BusinessDayStartHour AND CONVERT(TIME, @StartDate) <= @BusinessDayEndHour
            BEGIN
            IF (Select Count(*) From @Holidays h WHERE h.HDate=DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd,0,@StartDate), 0) OR (MONTH(h.HDate)=MONTH(@StartDate) AND DAY(h.HDate)=DAY(@StartDate) AND h.Recurring=1   )) = 0 
              BEGIN
                SET @MinutesDifference = @MinutesDifference + 1.0 --/ 60.00
                END
            END
        END
 
 
       

        SET @StartDate = DATEADD(SECOND, 1, @StartDate)
    END
    RETURN @MinutesDifference
END

And I have to call it in this query:
SELECT OperationId, StepI, StepII, StepIII, StepIV, StepV, StepVI 
FROM Operations

These are DATETIME columns and I should calculacte the time difference between StepI and StepII, then between StepII and StepIII and so on. Can you share your experiences with me? Thanks a lot.

You need to format your SQL as jo one can read it as it stands

Your SQL isn't valid. GO, for example, must be on it's own row, not part of a massively long line. You have comment out also all of the code, so your batch ends up simply being: SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetWorkingHoursDifferenceForTheSameWorkingHours] ( @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME, @BusinessDayStartHour VARCHAR(20),; which is far from a valid batch.

"that's why a scalar function is needed" Surely it's not "needed" to be a scalar function, and something like an inline table-value function that returns all six columns would be far better.

Sorry, I edited my query.

You know that you loop inside this function like a gazillion times, it's very slow. You should look for previous business functions

Another performance killer is the local table variable. It would be better if you rewrote your function to (1) Perform week arithmetic to calculate the number of whole weeks. (2) Directly calculate the number of regular and Saturday business days for those weeks. (3) Do the same for the partial first and last weeks (which might be the same week), including hours for partial days. (4) Count the number of holidays in the date range by directly querying the HrNav.Core.OffDays table and adjust your workday counts. (5) From your final workday and part-day hour counts, calculate the final hours.

The other approach is to define a calendar table (HrNav.Core might even already have one) that can then be selected for the given date range, adjustments made for start end end times, and total time aggregated all in a single query. Some CROSS APPLYs can be used to encapsulate intermediate calculations. Even without a calendar table, the GENERATE_SERIES() function can be used to generate a range of dates to replace your while loop. The solution depends on your SQL Server version.

What version of SQL Server are you using. Run the command select @@version and add the results to your question, or add a version-specific sql-server-nnnn tag.

Wait ... Are you looping through every second and checking the unindexed @Holiday table, using a complicated condition, once for every one of those seconds?

It's Mocrosoft SQL Server 2016

@MonikaEliashvili - I've updated my answer below to add 2016.-compatable code.

Your original code had several issues causing the performance issues: The main issue is that it was attempting to loop one-second at a time to count up the seconds of process time that overlapped the working hours. On top of that, for every second of process time counted, it was querying the local @Holidays table variable to check is the current date was a holiday.
Understanding the code was a bit tricky, since the function name implied hours, the function result variable was named @MinutesDifference, but the calculation was actually counting seconds.
I can think of two better approaches to this calculation:

If the date ranges are long (many weeks, months, or years), it might make sense to divide and conquer this task by calculating the time for the number of full weeks present (whole weeks x standard time per week), separately calculating values for the partial first and last weeks, and adjusting for holidays.

For smaller ranges of perhaps only a few days or weeks, calculating the results on a per-day basis and summing up the results may be the best approach.


Here is a potential replacement function that will:

Extract the date range and start/end times from the date/time range.
Convert all time-only values to integer seconds for comparisons and calculations. (This also allows for the concept of a 24:00:00 end-time.)
Use GENERATE_SERIES() to effective loop through the dates.
Calculate the effective start/end time for the current date - either of:

Start to 24:00 (start date)
00:00 to 24:00 (middle date)
00:00 to End (end date)
Start to End (start/end dates are the same)


Determine the working hours for the current date (regular, Saturday, Sunday, or Holiday)
Calculate the overlap in seconds between the above process and working times.
Sum up the results.

CREATE FUNCTION GetWorkingSecondsFast
(
     @StartDate DATETIME, 
     @EndDate DATETIME, 
     @BusinessDayStartHour VARCHAR(20),            -- 'hh:mm' or 'hh:mm:ss'
     @BusinessDayEndHour VARCHAR(20),              -- 'hh:mm' or 'hh:mm:ss' or '24:00' or '24:00:00'
     @BusinessDayStartHourForSaturday VARCHAR(20), -- 'hh:mm' or 'hh:mm:ss'
     @BusinessDayEndHourForSaturday VARCHAR(20)    -- 'hh:mm' or 'hh:mm:ss' or '24:00' or '24:00:00'
)
RETURNS INT -- Seconds
AS
BEGIN
    -- Convert start/end to dates and integer seconds 
    DECLARE @StartDay DATE = @StartDate
    DECLARE @EndDay DATE = @EndDate
    DECLARE @StartTimeSeconds INT = DATEDIFF(second, @StartDay, @StartDate)
    DECLARE @EndTimeSeconds INT = DATEDIFF(second, @EndDay, @EndDate)
    --DECLARE @StartTimeSeconds INT = DATEDIFF(second, '00:00', CAST(@StartDate AS TIME))
    --DECLARE @EndTimeSeconds INT = DATEDIFF(second, '00:00', CAST(@EndDate AS TIME))

    -- Convert business hours to integer seconds (special case '24:00' maps to 86400)
    DECLARE @NormalStartSeconds INT =
        DATEDIFF(second, '00:00', @BusinessDayStartHour)
    DECLARE @NormalEndSeconds INT =
        CASE WHEN @BusinessDayEndHour >= '24'
            THEN 86400
            ELSE DATEDIFF(second, '00:00', @BusinessDayEndHour) END
    DECLARE @SaturdayStartSeconds INT =
        DATEDIFF(second, '00:00', @BusinessDayStartHourForSaturday)
    DECLARE @SaturdayEndSeconds INT =
        CASE WHEN @BusinessDayEndHourForSaturday >= '24' THEN 86400 ELSE
            DATEDIFF(second, '00:00', @BusinessDayEndHourForSaturday) END
  
    DECLARE @Days INT = GREATEST(0, DATEDIFF(day, @StartDay, @EndDay))
    DECLARE @SaturdayDow INT = DATEPART(weekday,'2024-01-06') -- Known reference days
    DECLARE @SundayDow INT = DATEPART(weekday,'2024-01-07') -- Known reference days

    -- Use GENERATE_SERIES to effectively loop through the days in the range,
    -- use a series of CROSS APPLYs to calculate the overlapping workday period
    -- for each date, and sum up the total seconds.
    -- 
    -- Although the below looks complicated, most of the steps below are simple
    -- calculations with negligable performance overhead. Only the holiday lookup
    -- adds a non-trivial cost.
    DECLARE @TotalSeconds INT = (
        SELECT SUM(SEC.Seconds)
        FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, @Days) S -- For all days in start/end period
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(day, S.value, @StartDay) AS Date) D
        CROSS APPLY (
            -- Set start/end times for this date
            -- One of: start to 24:00, 00:00 to 24:00, 00:00 to end, or start to end
            SELECT
                CASE WHEN S.value = 0 THEN @StartTimeSeconds -- First day start
                    ELSE 0 END AS StartTimeSeconds, -- 00:00:00
                CASE WHEN S.value = @Days THEN @EndTimeSeconds -- Last day end
                    ELSE 86400 END AS EndTimeSeconds -- 24:00:00
        ) T
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEPART(weekday, D.Date) AS DayOfWeek) DW
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT
                CASE WHEN DW.DayOfWeek = @SaturdayDow THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsSaturday,
                CASE WHEN DW.DayOfWeek = @SundayDow THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsSunday,
                CASE WHEN EXISTS(
                        SELECT *
                        FROM OffDays OD
                        WHERE OD.HDay = D.Date
                        OR (
                           OD.Recurring = 1
                           AND MONTH(OD.HDay) = MONTH(D.Date)
                           AND DAY(OD.HDay) = DAY(D.Date)
                        )
                    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsHoliday
        ) DF
        CROSS APPLY (
            -- Pick the appropriate business hours
            SELECT
                CASE
                    WHEN DF.IsHoliday = 1 THEN 0
                    WHEN DF.IsSunday = 1 THEN 0
                    WHEN DF.IsSaturday = 1 THEN @SaturdayStartSeconds
                    ELSE @NormalStartSeconds
                    END AS WorkdayStartSeconds,
                CASE
                    WHEN DF.IsHoliday = 1 THEN 0
                    WHEN DF.IsSunday = 1 THEN 0
                    WHEN DF.IsSaturday = 1 THEN @SaturdayEndSeconds
                    ELSE @NormalEndSeconds
                    END AS WorkdayEndSeconds
        ) WD
        CROSS APPLY (
            -- Adjust the start/end times to reflect the workday overlap
            SELECT
                GREATEST(T.StartTimeSeconds, WD.WorkdayStartSeconds) AS AdjStartTimeSeconds,
                LEAST(T.EndTimeSeconds, WD.WorkdayEndSeconds) AS AdjEndTimeSeconds
        ) ADJ
        CROSS APPLY (
            -- Calculate seconds worked for this date, but don't allow negative.
            SELECT GREATEST(0, ADJ.AdjEndTimeSeconds - ADJ.AdjStartTimeSeconds) AS Seconds
        ) SEC
    )  

    RETURN @TotalSeconds
END

I intentionally performed calculation step-by-step across multiple CROSS APPLYs to clearly show the intermediate calculations. Some of these calculations could be combined to shorten code, but I do not believe there would be any performnce gain and the result may be arguably less-readable.
NOTE: The above uses GENERATE_SERIES(), GREATEST() and LEAST() functions available only in SQL Server 2022 and later. For earlier versions, GREATEST() and LEAST() can be replaced with equivalent CASE expressions or IIF() functions, while the GENERATE_SERIES()-based date generator logic can be replaced with a recursive CTE or any number of similar sequence generator techniques out there.
Sample results:



OriginalResult
FastResult
Id
StartDate
EndDate
Comments




3600.000
3600
1
2024-06-03 12:00
2024-06-03 13:00
One hour midday


1.000
1
2
2024-06-03 12:23:45
2024-06-03 12:23:46
One second midday


1800.000
1800
3
2024-06-03 09:30
2024-06-03 10:30
One hour, half overlapping workday start


1800.000
1800
4
2024-06-03 19:30
2024-06-03 20:30
One hour, half overlapping workday end


36001.000
36000
5
2024-06-03 00:00
2024-06-04 00:00
24-hour day


36001.000
18000
6
2024-06-08 00:00
2024-06-09 00:00
24-hour day Saturday


0.000
0
7
2024-06-09 00:00
2024-06-10 00:00
24-hour day Sunday


0.000
0
8
2024-06-11 00:00
2024-06-12 00:00
24-hour day holiday


0.000
0
9
2024-06-13 00:00
2024-06-14 00:00
24-hour day repeating holiday


7200.000
7200
10
2024-06-03 00:00
2024-06-03 12:00
AM only 00:00 - 12:00


28801.000
28800
11
2024-06-03 12:00
2024-06-04 00:00
PM only 12:00 - 24:00


7200.000
3600
12
2024-06-08 00:00
2024-06-08 12:00
AM only 00:00 - 12:00 Saturday


28801.000
14400
13
2024-06-08 12:00
2024-06-09 00:00
PM only 12:00 - 24:00 Saturday


0.000
0
16
2024-06-06 12:00
2024-06-06 12:00
zero hours: start = end


0.000
0
17
2024-06-06 14:00
2024-06-06 13:00
zero hours: start time > end time


0.000
0
18
2024-06-06 23:00
2024-06-06 02:00
zero hours: start time > end time


0.000
0
19
2024-12-31 12:00
2024-01-01 12:00
zero hours: start date > end date


Not run
108000
14
2024-06-03 12:00
2024-06-06 12:00
1/2 day + 2 full + 1/2 half regular days


Not run
252000
15
2024-06-06 12:00
2024-06-18 12:00
13 days, half start, half end, five full regular, two saturdays, two sundays, two holidays


Not run
1638000
20
2024-05-15 12:00
2024-07-15 12:00
About 2 months



The above test was run using:

10:00-20:00 normal working hours
11:00-16:00 Saturday working hours
2024-06-11 single holiday
1900-06-13 recurring holiday

See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
The above could be further improved if you could set up a calendar table with one row for every possible day in the history and near-future for your business. Logic like IsHoliday could be precalculated and the table could also directly define business hours for each date. This would then replace the date-generator and much other logic in the above function. Only the overlaps would need to be calculated, measured, and summed.
Here is a fiddle that shows a variation of the above logic that uses a calendar table.
SQL Server 2016 Versions
For SQL Server 2016, the following substitutions cam be made (with 2022 code commented out for comparison):
...
    --DECLARE @Days INT = GREATEST(0, DATEDIFF(day, @StartDay, @EndDay))
    DECLARE @Days INT = DATEDIFF(day, @StartDay, @EndDay)
    IF @Days < 0 SET @Days = 0
...
        --FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, @Days) S -- For all days in start/end period
        FROM (
            SELECT TOP (@Days + 1) --  0..@Days
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 AS value
                FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) n1(value)
                CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) n2(value) -- up to 100
                CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) n3(value) -- up to 1000
                CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) n4(value) -- up to 10,000
                -- Add more CROSS JOINs if needed based on expected max count.
        ) S  
...
                --GREATEST(T.StartTimeSeconds, WD.WorkdayStartSeconds) AS AdjStartTimeSeconds,
                --LEAST(T.EndTimeSeconds, WD.WorkdayEndSeconds) AS AdjEndTimeSeconds
                IIF(T.StartTimeSeconds > WD.WorkdayStartSeconds,
                    T.StartTimeSeconds, WD.WorkdayStartSeconds) AS AdjStartTimeSeconds,
                IIF(T.EndTimeSeconds < WD.WorkdayEndSeconds,
                    T.EndTimeSeconds, WD.WorkdayEndSeconds) AS AdjEndTimeSeconds
...
                --GREATEST(0, ADJ.AdjEndTimeSeconds - ADJ.AdjStartTimeSeconds) AS Seconds
                IIF(ADJ.AdjEndTimeSeconds < ADJ.AdjStartTimeSeconds,
                   0, ADJ.AdjEndTimeSeconds - ADJ.AdjStartTimeSeconds) AS Seconds
...

For the Calendar generator
...
-- Added
DECLARE @Days INT = DATEDIFF(day, @CalendarFromDate, @CalendarThruDate)
...
--FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, @Days) S
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (@Days + 1) --  0..@Days
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 AS value
        FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) n1(value)
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) n2(value) -- up to 100
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) n3(value) -- up to 1000
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) n4(value) -- up to 10,000
        -- Add more CROSS JOINs if needed based on expected max count.
) S  
...

In the calendar-based function:
...
                --GREATEST(T.StartTimeSeconds, C.WorkingHoursStartSeconds) AS AdjStartTimeSeconds,
                --LEAST(T.EndTimeSeconds, C.WorkingHoursEndSeconds) AS AdjEndTimeSeconds
                IIF(T.StartTimeSeconds > C.WorkingHoursStartSeconds,
                    T.StartTimeSeconds, C.WorkingHoursStartSeconds) AS AdjStartTimeSeconds,
                IIF(T.EndTimeSeconds < C.WorkingHoursEndSeconds,
                    T.EndTimeSeconds, C.WorkingHoursEndSeconds) AS AdjEndTimeSeconds
...
                --GREATEST(0, ADJ.AdjEndTimeSeconds - ADJ.AdjStartTimeSeconds) AS Seconds
                IIF(ADJ.AdjEndTimeSeconds < ADJ.AdjStartTimeSeconds,
                    0, ADJ.AdjEndTimeSeconds - ADJ.AdjStartTimeSeconds) AS Seconds
...

See this db<>fiddle for SQL Server 2016 versions of the non-calendar-based and calendar-based functions.
